# Cannot read property 'length' of null on Angular Service method call?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm modifying an existing Angular project (not mine), adding a new call to my external API.

This is the service method:

```js
getUserName(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(environment.apiUrl + URLS.USER_NAME)
}
```

And I use it on **appcomponent.ts** as following:

```js
this.userService.getUserName().subscribe((name) => { 
  this.user = name
})
```

When executing I get the following error:

> core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: **Cannot read property 'length' of null**
>       at **HttpHeaders**.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate
>   (http.js:199)
>       at http.js:170
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init
>   (http.js:170)
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach
>   (http.js:235)
>       at **Observable._subscribe** (http.js:1435)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:43)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:29)
>       at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call
>   (map.js:18)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:24)

It seems to be a headers problem or some subscribe/observable error, but I can't find where the error is.

- Is there something wrong with my code?
- It could be an existing interceptor that is modifying the request?

Note that the exception is thrown before making the request, so it must be a client problem when creating that request.

**Edit:**

This is the only interceptor I found:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TenantHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.indexOf(environment.apiTFSmin) === -1) {
      let tenantReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('current', sessionStorage.getItem('current')) })
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('tenant') != null && sessionStorage.getItem('newTenant') == null) {
        tenantReq = tenantReq.clone({ headers: tenantReq.headers.append('Tenant', sessionStorage.getItem('tenant')) })
      } else if (sessionStorage.getItem('newTenant') != null) {
        tenantReq = tenantReq.clone({ headers: tenantReq.headers.append('Tenant', sessionStorage.getItem('newTenant')) })
        sessionStorage.removeItem('newTenant')
      }
      if (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT') {
        tenantReq = tenantReq.clone({ headers: tenantReq.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json') })
      }
      return next.handle(tenantReq)
    } else {
      const tenantReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa('pescanilla-ext:m12345678*')) })
      // const tenantReq = req.clone()
      return next.handle(tenantReq)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have http interceptor ?

Comment: Question edited @Argon

Comment: check the import of httpClient in service file. ```import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the 'current' header to actually exist in the storage.

```
let tenantReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('current', sessionStorage.getItem('current')) })
```

**Edit:** The HttpClient will throw an error once you try to send a request with header with null value. Try replacing the `sessionStorage.getItem('current')` with a static value and test it.

Comment: Since its setting up it's not a case i think so

Comment: What do you mean by 'setting up'? He is not rewritting the header later on, it makes sense to me that it will fail because one of the headers is nullable.

Comment: Can you update your answer as you explaining and let him try that